# docker file does not execute

Tags: docker

I am trying to perform some test on vulnerable docker https://hub.docker.com/r/vulnerables/cve-2014-6271 but the docker is not actually executing. I Tested other docker images and they are working.

Here is the steps which I followed.

[image]

Just for confirmation that my docker is working properly here is the screenshot -

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Copy/paste the text and use the code formatting tool.

Comment: I can't read dark grey text on a darker background.